# Django: redirecting URL from auto-generated "?search_bar="

Tags: django, forms, get

So I am a new Django programmer and was wondering about how to pass a user-given value from a form into my URL address using Get method.

So I have this search bar, and when the user presses enter, it automatically creates a url address of "?search_bar=user_input"

But my urls.py, which is programmed to take the user_input variable, now fails to recognize my url address and my address is no longer matched to proceed to view.py.

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^class/(?P<user_input>\w+)', views.newview),
]
```

I understand that you cannot simply do the following because you shouldn't match query string with URL Dispatcher

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^class/?search_bar=(?P<user_input>\w+)', views.newview),
]
```

I should I solve this issue? How can I make the url.py recognize my new address and carry the user_input over to views.py?

Comment: You can't do that without JavaScript. But what's wrong with accessing the `user_input` from the GET query string, like: `user_input = request.GET.get('search')`?

Comment: thanks for the quick reply. My understanding is that when user presses enter, it goes through url.py and if you cannot match the current url with any other url patterns, it automatically raises errors before I can do user_input = request.get in views.py....

Comment: In that case, you'll need to change the url pattern, as suggested in the answer below.

Answer (score 2):

when we talk about `url` like `something/?search_bar=user_input` ,`something/` is the `url` part, and the `?search_bar=user_input` part belongs to the `GET` method,so :

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^class/$', views.newview),
]
```

and in your view.py:

```
def newview(request):
    user_input = request.GET['user_input']
    # or
    # user_input = request.GET.get('user_input', None)
```